# Python manage.py runserver throws an error

Tags: python, django, react-native

I have been running my python server for a few months now and I have had no problems, but ever since I have installed react-native I now get the following error.  I don't know if the python problem is related to the installation of react-native but it seems like a bit of coincidence.

Any help in solving this issue would be appreciated

```
File "manage.py", line 14
) from exc
     ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax code here
```

My manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_website.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Please post your code, so we can see what the problem looks like.

Comment: i got this error when i was trying to run makemigrations without activate python env

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this my installing python 3.7 and running

> py -3 manage.py runserver

I also had to reinstall the packages that were being used on my project

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a Python-3-specific Django version with a Python 2 interpreter. You will clearly see that if you look at the top of the full stacktrace

`raise ... from ...` is a Python 3 syntax. A Python 2 interpreter will treat it as a `SyntaxError` as can be demonstrated [here](https://repl.it/repls/CrowdedWeepyBytecode).

Make sure you are using Python 3 to execute this server.

Comment: I am using python 2.7.15 and Django 1.11.16

Comment: @JamiemcJames According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django Django 1.11.16 should be able to run with Python 2.7, but the fact is that your `manage.py` contains Python 3 only syntax

Comment: It's strange because its been running fine up until this point with that manage.py code